# How should I say "an empty file" in German?

Tags: english-to-german, sentence-structure

I want to tell someone the file which is being sent is "empty",

Maybe the proper translation of *empty* is "leer" and I found:

> [Leerdatei](http://de.bab.la/woerterbuch/englisch-deutsch/dummy-file) : dummy file

Is it the correct usage? While *dummy* is not really what I meant.

Comment: Do you mean an actually empty 0-byte file, or something like a form which has not been filled in?

Comment: @TimN: The person claimed by following the attachment, there are some folders in the file (also the file I wanted) but there's nothing inside. I'd like to reply to it that "the file is empty" or it's an "empty file".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In German, you'd say you will receive an empty file. In IT-context an empty file is known as "leere Datei".

**Correct possibilities are:**

> Sie haben mir eine leere Datei gesendet.
>
> Du hast mir eine leere Datei geschickt.
>
> Ich habe eine leere Datei erhalten.
>
> Eine leere Datei anlegen.
>
> Die leere Datei "xyz.xyz" öffnen.
>
> Ich werde eine leere Datei senden.

Comment: +1 And a useful correct possibility is: 'Eine leere Datei beziehungsweise leere Dateien **löschen**'

Comment: @florianb: Thanks, But I don't want to send an empty file, I'd like to inform a person that the file he has sent me is "empty".

Comment: @Gigili The file you have sent me is empty: Die von Ihnen gesendete Datei ist leer. (you can replace "Ihnen" with "dir" if you know the person well and would call him/her by his/her first name)

Comment: Ob man die Datei sendet oder empfängt - leer bleibt leer.

Comment: bei uns in der IT benutzen wir auch häufig englische Begriffe, zumindest teilweise. deshalb hätte ich jetzt spontan _leeres File_ als antwort gegeben. leere datei ist natürlich genauso korrekt.

Comment: Also possibly useful:  folder = Ordner, attachment = Anhang.

Answer (score 1):

"dummy is not really what I meant.". Then, don't use Leerdatei; say "eine leere Datei".

Or, if you really want to stress it, "inhaltslos" (it sounds slightly strange, but makes it exactly clear what you mean).

Comment: I would not use `inhaltslos` for. For me this sounds like the file is not empty (`leer`) but the content is meaningless/nonsensical (`bedeutungslos`). But you could say `die Datei hat keinen Inhalt` (the file has no content).

Answer (score 0):

Leerdatei ist ein guter Begriff.

Dummydatei kann in vielen Kontexten den Zweck der Leerdatei korrekt wiedergeben, aber wie Du richtig vermutest gibt es Leerdateien die keine Dummydatei sind, beispielsweise eine Datei die aufgrund eines Fehlers leer geblieben ist.

Mit "eine leere Datei" wird aber nichts anderes ausgedrückt als mit Leerdatei; derartige Empfehlungen sind schlicht falsch.

Comment: "Leerdatei" klingt sehr ungewöhnlich; möglicherweise wie einer der Begriffe, die man in älteren Lehrbüchern und Benutzerhandbüchern findet, die aber nie wirklich Eingang in die tatsächlich gebräuchliche Sprache im Bezug auf Computer gefunden haben oder inzwischen bereits aus ihr verschwunden sind. "Leere Datei" ist meines Erachtens die deutlich natürlichere Bezeichnung. Man spricht schließlich auch nicht von einem "Leergeldbeutel" oder einem "Leermülleimer".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Ein Ausdruck muss nicht populär sein, um richtig zu sein und verstanden zu werden. Die Substantivverschmelzung im Deutschen macht Begriffe wie Leerdatei auch dann möglich, wenn sie zuvor noch nie jemand benutzt hat. Man spricht auch von Leerkasetten, Leercontainern, Leerfahrten usw.

Comment: Ich behaupte ja nicht, dass der Ausdruck nicht möglich oder verständlich ist, sondern nur, dass er wohl eher nicht so gebräuchlich wie "leere Datei" ist. Das macht Letzteres noch lange nicht "schlicht falsch". Und, ja, natürlich gibt es die Begriffe "Leerkassette", "Leercontainer", "Leerfahrt" etc. - dennoch sind solche Begriffe tendenziell eher dem Fachjargon zuzuordnen. Insbesondere bei den Containern würde wohl jeder, der nicht gerade in der Logistikbranche tätig ist, von einem "leeren Container" sprechen statt von einem "Leercontainer". Der Begriff "Leerfahrt" mag zwar einigermaßen ...

Comment: ... verbreitet sein, aber eben auch nur, weil er von Verkehrsbetreibern häufig öffentlichkeitswirksam an Zügen, die ebensolche Leerfahrten durchführen, angezeigt wird (und möglicherweise auch, weil es bereits eine Verkürzung der eigentlich Bedeutung einer "Fahrt mit einem geplant leeren Fahrzeug" darstellt, also schon eine Art "Spezialbezeichnung" für einen komplexeren Sachverhalt ist). Meiner Meinung nach ist trotzdem die "allgemeinverträgliche" Variante, die man zunächst mal anwenden sollte, wenn man nicht ganz sicher ist, für ein bestimmtes Zielpublikum zu schreiben, die getrennte Variante.

Comment: Ich bin weder in der Logistikbranche tätig, noch im Taxigewerbe, und doch sind mir Leercontainer und Leerfahrt geläufig und gehen mir leicht über die Lippen, letzteres hat übrigens mit "geplant" nix zu tun. Leerkassetten und -disketten war die übliche Handelsbezeichnung, als es diese Medien noch massenweise gab. An Zügen habe ich "Leerfahrt" noch nie gesehen, an Bussen steht hier immer "Betriebsfahrt". Das die Formen mit "Leer"~ irgendwie unverträglich sein sollen verstehe ich inhaltlich nicht - was soll das heißen? Kabeljau-Cordon-Bleu versteht man auch ohne das Wort vorher gehört zu haben.

Comment: Unter einer "Leerfahrt" hätte ich jetzt schon ausschließlich die Fahrten verstanden, bei denen absichtlich keine Fahrgäste aufgenommen wurden, und nicht die, wo eben nur zufällig gerade niemand eingestiegen ist. An Verkehrsmitteln steht je nach Betreiber schon auch Leerfahrt ([Bus](http://www.imgbox.de/users/Thomas478/H_Busse_2/249_ex_AC122_20140918_Westercellertorstr_b.jpg), [U-Bahn](http://www.bahnbilder.de/1024/u5-50-wagen-nummer-828-auf-695540.jpg)). Sicher *versteht* man die zusammengesetzte Konstruktion - dennoch klingen meiner Meinung nach "Leersupermarkt", "Leercontainer" und ...

Comment: ... "Leerstraße" weniger gebräuchlich als "leerer Supermarkt", "leerer Container" und "leere Straße". Dass "Leerkassette" und "Leerdiskette" wiederum der Fachjargon unter den Händlern von Speichermedien ist oder war, mag ja sein, aber das bedeutet ja trotzdem nicht, dass der Begriff tatsächlich allgemein benutzt wird. Immerhin ist auch "Beförderungsentgelt" eine alltägliche Bezeichnung im Fahrkartenverkauf, aber eben nur innerhalb von Verkehrsunternehmen, während der Rest der Welt - inklusive der Kunden - von einem "Fahrpreis" spricht.

Comment: Das sind sehr schöne Beispiele dafür, dass Verkehrsbetriebe die Bezeichnung benutzen, allerdings folgert daraus nicht, dass Laien und Kunden die Begriffe nicht benutzen, nur darum geht's Dir doch. Bei Leerkassette/Leerdiskette ist es ebenso: Dass die Händler und Produzenten - hier aber nicht öffentliche Betriebe aus Willhelminischen Zeiten - die Bezeichnung benutzt haben sollte zeigen, dass sie gebräuchlich waren und das waren sie - nicht dass es Spezialistenjargon war. "Unverträglich" ist noch nicht erklärt. Kindische Strohmänner wie "Leersupermarkt" bitte nicht nochmal probieren.

Comment: Ich halte die zusammengesetzte Variante für weniger allgemeinverträglich, weil "Leercontainer" nun mal einfach merkwürdig klingt, genau wie der ja auch von dir als ungewöhnlich empfundene "Leersupermarkt". Händler und Produzenten mögen bestimmte Begriffe verwenden, aber sind Händler und Produzenten in ihrem Gebiet denn keine Spezialisten? Letztendlich geht es mir aber nur darum, zum Ausdruck zu bringen, dass an der Empfehlung, "empty file" mit "leere Datei" zu übersetzen, überhaupt nichts "schlicht falsch" ist, wie in deiner Antwort behauptet.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Ich habe nie behauptet dass "leere Datei" schlicht falsch ist, sondern die Behauptung, Leerdatei sei ungeeignet, ist schlicht falsch. 2.: Was ist denn ein Leersupermarkt - einer ohne Waren oder ohne Kunden? 3.: Nicht nur Händler, sondern auch Kunden und Benutzer sprachen von Leerkassetten/-disketten. "Kannst Du mir die Platte aufnehmen?" "Ja, wenn Du mir eine Leerkassette gibst."

Comment: 1. Ok, dann habe ich den Bezug von "schlicht falsch" nicht so verstanden, wie du ihn in der Antwort meintest. 2. Die genaue Bedeutung ist bei so was ja meistens rein durch Konventionen bestimmt - eine Leerfahrt könnte schließlich auch eine Fahrt ohne Treibstoff oder ohne Fahrzeugeinrichtung sein, wenn man nicht weiß, was gemeint ist. 3. "Ja, wenn Du mir eine Leerkassette gibst." klingt für mich wie gesagt sonderbar. Möglicherweise ist es ein regionaler Unterschied, aber meiner Meinung nach klingt "Ja, wenn du mir eine leere Kassette gibst." einfach natürlicher.